# Error when calling the metaclass bases

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Finding it very difficult to wrap around this basic problem. I'm using python 2.7.10 to follow a flask tutorial being delivered using python 3.4. I'm aware of some differences between the two versions, but seems that knowledge isn't enough to overcome this situation. I have amateur level experience in python. Have a feeling its got something to do with class definition, but unable to nail it. And yes i went through the solutions for similar error but wasn't able to relate the solution to my problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_init import app
  File "/Users/sapp/Desktop/ude/flask_init/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from author import views
  File "/Users/sapp/Desktop/ude/flask_init/author/views.py", line 3, in     <module>
    from form import RegisterForm
   File "/Users/sapp/Desktop/ude/flask_init/author/form.py", line 5, in <module>
    class RegisterForm(form):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

My directory structure:

```
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── author
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── form.py
│   ├── form.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
├── templates
│   ├── author
│   └── base.html
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── pip-selfcheck.json
```

manage.py:

```
import os, sys

from flask_script import Manager, Server
from flask_init import app

manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
    do something
    ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

form.py:

```
from flask_wtf import form
from wtforms import validators, StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import EmailField

class RegisterForm(form):
    pass
```

init.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('settings')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
import blog.views
from author import views
```

views.py:

```
from flask_init import app
from flask import render_template, redirect
from form import RegisterForm

@app.route('/register', method=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render_template('author/register.html', form=form)
```

I chose not to tag with wtforms as i'm more concerned with what i'm missing when it comes to metaclasses between 2.7 and 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python versions.

You're importing the wrong thing in your form.py; you have `form` instead of `Form`. The former is a module, the latter is the class, which is what you should be inheriting from.

Comment: Thank you. Also had 'method' instead of 'methods' in views.py. All set!